# Is there a way to comment out a large block of code in TextMate?

Tags: ruby, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I don't see anything in the Ruby bundle that will help me add comments to a large block of code. The links I have found online to such a shortcut do not appear to be valid any more.

Comment: There hasn't been an  Apple symbol on that key since maybe... Apple ][e?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not Ruby-specific: the same shortcut works for every languages and is found in the "Source" bundle.

It's <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>